# Parallel processes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am curious to know if it is possible to run a python script that calls a function as parallel child processes. I'm not sure I'm using these terms correctly so here's a concept script fashioned from a bash script that does what I'm talking about.

```
import Zfunctions as Z
reload(Z)

def Parallel():
    statements
    calls to other functions in a general function file Z

#--------------
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    # Running this script in a linux cluster with 8 processing node available
    Parallel() &  #1st process sent to 1st processing node
    Parallell() & #2nd process sent to 2nd node
    .
    .
    .
    Parallell() & #8th process sent to 8th node
    wait
```

Now I know the ampersand (&) and "wait" are wrong here but in the bash it is the way to sent the process to the background and wait for these processes to finish. My question is now, hopefully clearer: Can this be done in python, and if so how?

Any help is appreciated.

/M

I have gotten some good help. I tested this modification my question above which tries to run 60 jobs that will process a huge amount of data and write the results to disk. All this is in a single python file that combines two for loops and a series of internal functions calls. The script fails and the error output is found below:

```
import multiprocessing

def Parallel(m,w,PROCESSES):                                                             
plist = {}                                                                           
plist['timespan'] = '2007-2008'                                                      
print 'Creating pool with %d processes\n' % PROCESSES                                
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(PROCESSES)                                               
print 'pool = %s' % pool                                                             

TASKS = [(LRCE,(plist,m,w)),(SRCE,(plist,m,w)),(ALBEDO,(plist,m,w)),                 
         (SW,(plist,m,w)),(RR,(plist,m,w)),(OLR,(plist,m,w)),(TRMM,(plist,w)),       
         (IWP,(plist,m,w)),(RH,(plist,'uth',m,w)),(RH,(plist,200,m,w)),              
         (RH,(plist,400,m,w)),(IWC,(plist,200,m,w)),(IWC,(plist,400,m,w)),           
         (CC,(plist,200,m,w)),(CC,(plist,400,m,w))]                                                                                                        

results = [pool.apply_async(calculate,t) for t in TASKS]                             
print 'Ordered results using pool.apply_async():'                                    
for r in results:                                                                    
    print '\t', r.get()                                                              

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                               
PROCESSES = 8                                                                        
for w in np.arange(2):                                                               
    for m in np.arange(2):                                                           
        Parallel(m,w,PROCESSES)
```

#### error message from cluster

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/software/apps/python/2.7.2-smhi1/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in **bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/software/apps/python/2.7.2-smhi1/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/software/apps/python/2.7.2-smhi1/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 313, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup __builtin**.function failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look into [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) -- your code could be accomplished as follows:

```
import multiprocessing

def Parallel(junk):    
    #...snip...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)

   results = p.map(Parallel, range(8))
```

One warning:  Don't try this in an interactive interpreter.

Comment: The code would not return any data. Would it work with just:
    p.map(Parallel,range(8))?

How does "results" look like if each parallel call is independent of each other?

Comment: @Shejo284 -- python functions always return *something*.  Even without an explicit `return` statement, they return `None`.  So, in this case, you'd get a list of 8 `None` values.  You can choose not to store it though:  `p.map(Parallel,range(8))` instead of `results = p.map(Parallel, range(8))`.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Two final questions, if I may. If I wanted to run a set of different functions in addition to Parallel:
   results = p.map([Parallel,f2,f3,...f8], range(8))
Would this work?

What about waiting until each process is complete before the call:
   results = p.map(Parallel, range(8))
could be repeated?

Comment: @Shejo284 -- I'm confused.  Do you want each process to run `f1,f2,f3 ...` in order before returning?  If that's the case, just wrap them up in another function.  (with `Pool.map` you can only call 1 function).  If you want `f1` to run 8 times, wait, then run `f2` 8 times, you can just `Pool.map` again to run f2. Does that answer your question? Note that `Pool.map` will wait until all the processes have completed no matter what. If you don't want to wait, `Pool.apply_async` could be what you want which will behave more similarly to the `&` in bash. Take a look at the documentation in the link.

Comment: @ mgilson -- My question has evolved somewhat (see edited edition above). I think the **Pool.apply_async** is what I need but testing is not possible, as you pointed out in interactive mode. Submitting this to my cluster will take hours to run. Would love more help with the partial solution above. I think I need a condition, according to the documentation but I'm not sure how to implement it.